# The same background music playing in all activities

Tags: android, android-service

I use services to play background music in all activities and it works. The problem is the music continues playing even if my app is in background (when user exit with home button or back button). How can I solve this?

Services class `BackgroundSoundService`

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = null;
    MediaPlayer player;
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.slow_shock);
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(100,100);

    }
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        player.start();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // TO DO
    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TO DO Auto-generated method
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        player.stop();
        player.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

Starting with

```
Intent svc = new Intent(this, BackgroundSoundService.class);
    startService(svc);
```

Android Manifest:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name=".BackgroundSoundService" />
```

Comment: Another suggestion is to use 1 Activity with multiple Fragments. In that case you do not need a service and the sound logic can depend on Activity's lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happened because the Service is still bounded in the activity. To terminate the service when multiple activity is bound to the service, you need to unbind the service from all of them as in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Lifecycle) says:

> The service lifecycle—from when it's created to when it's
>   destroyed—can follow either of these two paths:
>
> A started service
>
> The service is created when another component calls startService().
>   The service then runs indefinitely and must stop itself by calling
>   stopSelf(). Another component can also stop the service by calling
>   stopService(). When the service is stopped, the system destroys it.
>
> A bound service
>
> The service is created when another component (a client) calls
>   bindService(). The client then communicates with the service through
>   an IBinder interface. The client can close the connection by calling
>   unbindService(). Multiple clients can bind to the same service and
>   when all of them unbind, the system destroys the service. The service
>   does not need to stop itself.
>
> These two paths are not entirely separate. You can bind to a service
>   that is already started with startService(). For example, you can
>   start a background music service by calling startService() with an
>   Intent that identifies the music to play. Later, possibly when the
>   user wants to exercise some control over the player or get information
>   about the current song, an activity can bind to the service by calling
>   bindService(). In cases such as this, stopService() or stopSelf()
>   doesn't actually stop the service until all of the clients unbind.

Then call `Context.stopService()` to stop it:

```
context.stopService(new Intent(context, BackgroundSoundService.class));
```